Why do i get captcha when posting a question?
Why do i get captcha when posting a question?
Besides that - captchas cost like $1 for 1000 and don't protect from bots. They just annoy legal users.

I'm not sure why you did get a captcha ... I didn't see any for a long time. I think there is some heuristics ... when your question looks a bit like spam, for example. I suppose Stack Exchange will not publish the exact details of this.

And how long will it treat my posts as spam? Must i accept it and continue entering captchas before every question?

Rumours say that the more voted answers you write, the less captchas you get.
